# Simple custom attribute or textfield for categories

Tags: admin, attributes, setup-script

I would like to add a textfield or an attribute for my categories in Manage Categories. What is the best & simplest way to achieve this? I am open to the idea of [adding a custom module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_add_a_custom_module_for_custom_admin_config_options) to achieve this however, am not sure if this is actually possible without making a setup script and/or by doing changes to the database.

Comment: There are a number of available resources online that already discuss this. Try searching `Magento category attribute`

Comment: @pspahn I am aware there are a number of ways to achieve this but was after an answer explaining what is best practice.

Comment: Whether you do this in your own branded module with install script or simply drop some code in a template file and run it once (among other methods) is going to depend on what you're doing. If you have specific concerns about "best practice" you should mention those since "best practice" may vary depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an installer like this one, but you need to change the type,the input if you want to save text, and the attribute group (in this case is "Display Settings")

```
    <?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, "Display Settings" );

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'your_attribute_code',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'Your label',
    'input'    => 'select',
    'source'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'required' => false,
    'default'  => 1
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'your_attribute_code',
    '32'
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

And you need to define the class of the setup in the config.xml like this

```
    <config>
...
        <resources>
            <your_extension_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Your_extension</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </your_extension_setup>
        </resources>
...
    </config>
```